# How select locale for inline translations in Magento2? How use in Magento2 inline translations with chosen locale in code?

Tags: php, translation, magento2

We need to have ability in code use inline translations with translated strings from csv files with selected locale, which is different from store. For example, user select english language in frontend, but we want to create PDF or rend email with de_DE translations. 
We want to get something like this (not correct this code)

```
> setLocale('de_DE');
> __('Good morning');
```

> `// Guten Morgen`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just set the locale through the admin console (to `de_DE` in this case) then find the relevant `i18n` directory and add the translation CSV. For instance, using the default `Luma` theme, the directory is `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/i18n`; make a copy of `en_US.csv` and name it `de_DE.csv` and make your translations in there... **however** that only covers the text relevant to the `Luma` module, **every** module should have it's own `i18n` directory and corresponding CSV translation files. Though you should be able to create your own module/helper to handle it.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Comment: Thanks for help. I know all this. I have setUp by default, for example, English. Plus shop has many languages in Frontend for clients. And we have all translations in csv files in correct folders. everything work good. BUT, i want select directly in code to what language will translate strings, despite default locale in Backend and selected language for shop by Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have found the solution!!!!** I have tried a lot of code and recommendations. But for me one way to solve my problem is next: 
So in Magento\Framework\App\Language\Dictionary class exist

```
function getDictionary($locale)
```

what returns array from csv files for selected locale. then I just get value from array by key - default string in base language - English.